# How to send Image from one component to another component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactJS, Currently I have Image in one component and I want to send this image to another. Could you please help me how I can send this image to another component. If you give me example it would be better

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "you have an image"?

Comment: You send data to other components by props in React. So send the image URL by a prop to the other components.

Comment: You have a few options. The two most popular are 1. put it in a parent component and pass to both child components as props (moving data up the chain) and 2. using a data and state management solution like mobx or redux. Detailing how to do all of this is beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: I guess OP is asking for Shared Element Transition. if that's the case, here's a cool example: https://codepen.io/Penno/pen/WXRjMY

Comment: I couldn't add my answer bc the question is on hold...maybe add a little more info to your question

Answer (score 1):

If this image needs to be accesible from different components, consider making it part of either a global configuration (if it's a fixed value), put in on the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), save it to localStorage, or save it in the store so it can be accessed from anywhere in the app.